# TYPO3 restricted user Image Adjustments

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, typoscript, tsconfig

In TYPO3 BE I miss the Image Adjustments dialog in page element images and text with images. When I'm editing such an element, I miss this dialog which is for the admin user placed in the tab appearance. I think it's because the dialog is based on imagemagick which is disabled by default for an restricted user?!

For a restricted user it is missed.

Any idea how to configure the restricted users TSConfig to enable  Image Adjustments? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Admin Tools->usergroup->Access Lists->**Allowed excludefields** you have to active the Page Content **Width (pixels)(imagewidth)** and **Height (pixels)(imageheight)**.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to give the user access to the `image_effects (tt_content)` field.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry comment form is too short for this.

How do you mean this pgame? 
According to this descr. 
http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/typo3-4-x-backend/13748-bereiche-backends-fuer-bestimmte-user-ausbleden.html 
i set in the user TSConfig 
 `TCEFORM.tt_content.image_effects.disabled = 0`

But like described in the last post on that page it just works for Page TSConfig, not for user TSConfig. I tried some other TSConfig's like

`admPanel.override.image.settings = 1`
 and

`admPanel.override.imageblock = 1`

More or less influenced by http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsconfig/4.1.0/view/1/2/ and the descr. there under the admpanel override section, where's descr. "you can have a look at the HTML code of the admin panel" but no positive results ?! Anybody an idea. The dialog image settings and its resize func. use the fields imagewidth and imageheight from tt_content. I can not found anything useful with google, this typo3 usermanagement kill my nerves )-;

Comment: I'm also found this sad, unsolved thread with same topic: http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/typo3-4-x-fragen-probleme/42083-image-user-berechtigungen.html

Comment: And here same unsolved topic from my own 1 year ago http://www.typo3.net/forum/beitraege/benutzerrechte/106835/beitrag/seite/#pid397956